# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, string, printing, integer

I have this python program that adds strings to integers:

```
a = raw_input("Enter a: ")
b = raw_input("Enter b: ")
print "a + b as strings: " + a + b
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
c = a + b
str(c)
print "a + b as integers: " + c
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

How can I add strings to integers?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

There are two ways to fix the problem which is caused by the last `print` statement.

You can assign the result of the `str(c)` call to `c` as correctly shown by @jamylak and then concatenate all of the strings, or you can replace the last `print` simply with this:

```
print "a + b as integers: ", c  # note the comma here
```

in which case

```
str(c)
```

isn't necessary and can be deleted.

Output of sample run:

```
Enter a: 3
Enter b: 7
a + b as strings:  37
a + b as integers:  10
```

with:

```
a = raw_input("Enter a: ")
b = raw_input("Enter b: ")
print "a + b as strings: " + a + b  # + everywhere is ok since all are strings
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
c = a + b
print "a + b as integers: ", c
```

Answer (score 86):

`str(c)` returns a **new** string representation of `c`, and does not mutate `c` itself.

```
c = str(c)
```

is probably what you are looking for

Comment: I don't think the `str(c)` is necessary at all for the program (though what you say about having to assign the result of the function is correct)

Comment: It's not necessary I agree, but it is the reason why it doesn't work as is.

Comment: You can leave it in, it doesn't cause an problems (just as it doesn't really do anything :)

Comment: If you remove it, you must change the following line to `print "a + b as integers: ", c`, though.

Comment: @Levon I +1d for you "alternate" approach

Answer (score 23):

If you want to concatenate int or floats to a string you must use this:

```
i = 123
a = "foobar"
s = a + str(i)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
c = a + b 
str(c)
```

Actually, in this last line you are not changing the type of the variable c. If you do

```
c_str=str(c)
print "a + b as integers: " + c_str
```

it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from other answers, one could also use `format()`

`print("a + b as integers: {}".format(c))`

For example -

```
hours = 13
minutes = 32
print("Time elapsed - {} hours and {} minutes".format(hours, minutes))
```

will result in output - `Time elapsed - 13 hours and 32 minutes`

Check out [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `int` into `str` using string function:

```
user = "mohan"

line = str(50)

print(user + "typed" + line + "lines")
```

Comment: This has already been answered by others. Your answer doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and least confusing solution:

```
a = raw_input("Enter a: ")
b = raw_input("Enter b: ")
print "a + b as strings: %s" % a  + b
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
c = a + b
print "a + b as integers: %d" % c
```

I found this on http://freecodeszone.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

I also had the error message "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". It turns out that I only just forgot to add str() around a variable when printing it. Here is my code:

```js
def main():
 rolling = True; import random
 while rolling:
  roll = input("ENTER = roll; Q = quit ")
  if roll.lower() != 'q':
   num = (random.randint(1,6))
   print("----------------------"); print("you rolled " + str(num))
  else:
   rolling = False
main()
```

I know, it was a stupid mistake but for beginners who are very new to python such as myself, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have done to get rid of this error separating variable with "," helped me.

```
# Applying BODMAS 
arg3 = int((2 + 3) * 45 / - 2)
arg4 = "Value "
print arg4, "is", arg3
```

**Here is the output**

### Value  is -113

(program exited with code: 0)