# changing an integer to a string "implicitly"?? Python

Tags: python, string

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm really new to this and I need to convert my input into a string?

```
# Python program to calculate the Fibonacci numbers
def fibR(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibR(n - 1) + fibR(n - 2)

# Request input from the user
num = int(input("Please enter the number in the Fibonacci sequence you wish to calculate: "))

#
if num == 1:
    print("The Fibonacci number you have requested is" + 1 + ".")
else :
    print("The Fibonacci number you have requested is" + fibR(num) + ".")
```

Comment: Your input is a string already. You convert it into an `int`..

Comment: Did you google "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"? Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844072/python-typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-int-objects)

Comment: Why do you avoid calling your `fibR` function in the `n == 1` case? It's not like it will cause a performance issue for 1. (It will for large `n`, though.)

Answer (score 3):

You are already converting your `input` into an `int` correctly. However, in your `print` statement...

```
print("The Fibonacci number you have requested is" + fibR(num) + ".")
```

....the function `fibR(num)` is returning an integer. When you try and concatenate the returned integer with the string, it causes an error. What you need to do instead is use format strings:

```
print("The Fibonacci number you have requested is {}.".format(fibR(num)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm really trying to improve myself. Oh and by the way it's she not he.

Answer (score 1):

Do [`str(number)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) to convert a number to string.

Answer (score 1):

In `else` statement use `%`:

```
print("The Fibonacci number you have requested is %d." % fibR(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
import this
```

you'll learn that the makers of Python think

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Thus, in Python you can just 'add' `string`s and `int`s as you try to do in your two `print` statements. Either explicitly convert the number to a string by using the return value of `str(fibR(num))`, or, even better, look into [`string`'s `format()` method](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Some examples on how to use it have already be given by the other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `str()` method:

```
print("The Fibonacci number you have requested is" + str(fibR(num)) + ".")
```