# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str SUM

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that will sum the cube of a number up to an upper boundary.

The mathematical formula is (n*(n+1)/2)^2

My code in Python:

```
def cube_numbers():
   upper_boundary = 0
   cube_sum = 0
   upper_boundary = input("Please enter the upper boundary:")
   cube_sum = ((upper_boundary * (upper_boundary + 1) / 2)**2)
   print("The sum of the cube of numbers up to" & upper_boundary & "is" & cube_sum)
#main
cube_numbers()
```

But I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/barki/Desktop/sum of cubes.py", line 10, in <module>
    cube_numbers()

  File "C:/Users/barki/Desktop/sum of cubes.py", line 5, in cube_numbers
    cube_sum = ((upper_boundary * (upper_boundary + 1) / 2)**2)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Once again: `input(..)` returns a `str`ing, not an `int`, use `upper_boundary = int(upper_boundary)` to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: local variable 'upper_boundary' referenced before assignment

Comment: **after** you assigned it with `input(..)` of course... I'm quite cursious why you tink you can call a function on a not yet assigned variable?

Comment: Also i didnt know that. now it is fixed, thank you

Comment: well some languages allow to call a function with variables that are defined later, so I'm not saying you're an idiot :)

Comment: no i know you didnt call me an idiot, i did :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str (simple Python programme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225721/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str-simple-python-programme)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of your function should not be to `print`.  Also it would be better to move your `input` prompt out of your function and then pass that value into your function.  What we can do then is get the input for `upper_boundary` as an `int` and then pass that to `cube_numbers`. That return value will now be `cube_sum` and we can use formatted printing to print out the statment.

```
def cube_numbers(x):
    y = int(((x * (x + 1) / 2)**2))
    return y

upper_boundary = int(input("Please enter the upper boundary: "))
cube_sum = cube_numbers(upper_boundary)

print('The sum of the cube of numbers up to {} is {}.'.format(upper_boundary, cube_sum))
# The sum of the cube of numbers up to 10 is 3025.
```

Answer (score 0):

> print("The sum of the cube of numbers up to" & upper_boundary & "is" & cube_sum)

You should format your code properly, either by using `.format` notation or separating different values by `,` or conacatinating them by converting integer type values to string using `str` (not recommended)

Always use the `.format` notation for formatting.

example,

```
print("The sum of the cube of numbers up to {} is {}".format(upper_boundary, cube_sum))
```

You can also use indexing for formatting:

example,

```
print("The sum of the cube of numbers up to {0} is {1}".format(upper_boundary, cube_sum))
```

In this case whatever is at the first place inside the format method will take the "0th" place in the string.

Another way to do this is by actually supplying some names as the placeholder:

example,

```
print("The sum of the cube of numbers up to {upper_bnd} is {cube_sm}".format(upper_bnd = upper_boundary, cube_sm = cube_sum))
```

Hope this helps.