# Variable error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

I'm writing in Python the following lines:

```
age = input("How old are you?")
```

I press return then I have to answer the question, I'm saying I'm 13,
Then I type:

```
ageNextYear = age + 1
```

I press return so I can do the next step from the book (I'm a starter with coding in general) and it tells me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    ageNextYear = age + 1 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str (simple Python programme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225721/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str-simple-python-programme)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the user input to integer, that's it you are good to go,

```
age = int(input("How old are you?"))
ageNextYear = age + 1
print(ageNextYear)
```